# Can not call WCF Service hosted in a Managed Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, service

So I have some Issue regarding a WCF Service that is hosted in a Managed Windows Service.

Basically what I did is the following:

I created a WCF Service Lib (the WCF Service template ) using a simple test, like this

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IExample
{
    [OperationContract]
    string HelloWorld();
}

public class Example : IExample
{
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "HelloWorld";
    }
}
```

I also created a corresponding app.config which is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
            <!-- This section is optional with the new configuration model introduced in .NET Framework 4. -->
            <service name="Peripherie.WCFService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8067/PeripherieService"/>
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Peripherie.WCFService.Interfaces.IExample" />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

After that I added a Win Service project (again with the Win Service template) which references the above lib and the other needed libs.

In the Service class i do the basic stuff to create the servicehost

```
public partial class Service : ServiceBase
{
    public ServiceHost serviceHost = null;

    public Service()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }

   protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
   {
       if(serviceHost!=null)
        serviceHost.Close();

       serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service));

       serviceHost.Open();
   }

   protected override void OnStop()
   {
       if(serviceHost!=null)
       {
        serviceHost.Close();
        serviceHost = null;
       }
   }
}
```

I also added the needed Installer for the Service and set the account to localSystem.

The whole project compiles just fine and I am also able to install the service (using the installutil approach) and start it as well. However when ever I try to open the the Service in the browser I get the error that the side could not be loaded, I am also not able to use the WCF Test Client as it tells me that there are is no metadata to be retrieved.

I dont really get why the whole think does not work, as it seems that everything is setup correctly.

So any advice would be nice.

Edit:

After fixing the mistake pointed out by SouthShoreAK I also found an error in the config, where this:

```
<service name="Peripherie.WCFService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
```

should have been this:

```
<service name="Peripherie.WCFService.Services.Example" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
```

Now I get the error that the url could not be registered,

```
System.ServiceModel.AddressAccessDeniedException: HTTP konnte URL "http://+:8067/PeripherieService/" nicht registrieren. Der Prozess weist keine Zugriffsrechte für diesen Namespace auf
```

I already tried the tool described [HERE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paulwh/archive/2007/05/04/addressaccessdeniedexception-http-could-not-register-url-http-8080.aspx) however that did not solve the error. Still can start the Service because of the error.

Edit:

Okay that issue was resolved as well, I have the service process installer still set to networkService. After setting it to local system I can start the service now.

but still I get an error 400 now when calling the url via IE.

Final Edit:

Okay now it works, last error was because of a missing / at the end of the base address. So it should have been

```
<add baseAddress="http://localhost:8067/PeripherieService/"/>
```

And since SouthShoreAK pretty much pointed me towards the mistakes I made in my config I will accept his answer, because it got me on track.

Comment: Two points: **(1)** the `<service name="...." >` attribute **must** exactly match the class (including its namespaces) that **implements** the service, and **(2)** that class needs to be used in the `new ServiceHost(typeof(....))` as well

Comment: yeah I did that already and it indeed fixed the error I had earlier now all that remains seems to be some rights issue regarding my user account.

Comment: okay fixed the issue with the user account (see las edit) but still getting the 400 error :/

Comment: Finally it works, there was a / missing at the end of the base address...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your contract should be IExample, not IMain

```
 <endpoint name="ServiceHttpEndpoint" address="http://localhost:8067/PeripherieService" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Peripherie.WCFService.Interfaces.IMain" />
```

Should be changed to:

```
 <endpoint name="ServiceHttpEndpoint" address="http://localhost:8067/PeripherieService" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Peripherie.WCFService.Interfaces.IExample" />
```

Also, this:

```
serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service));
```

Should be this:

```
serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Example));
```

You're trying to register and instance of your Windows service in the service host. You should be registering your WCF service.

Sometimes I've found that your windows service will start and run even when the Service Host encounters an error. You may want to check your Windows Event Log (just type "Event Viewer" in the start menu) to see if anything went wrong.

Comment: yeah I saw that, was just an old config file i posted. the new one has the correct link sorry. But Still the issue remains.

Comment: okay it seems the second error you pointed out really was a mistake. I fixed it and if I start the service now, it says that it started the service and then stopped it. could there be an exception within the OnStart ?

Comment: What does your event log say?

Comment: yep it says that i could not find an endpoint, I made a mistake and simply put the config in the lib, so the actuall config for the service does not have any endpoints.

Comment: Okay strange I now put the config content in the app.config of the service and this content is also in the peripherie.winservice.exe.config. however the log still says there is an exception

Comment: System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.EnsureThereAreApplicationEndpoints(ServiceDescription description)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.InitializeServiceHost(ServiceDescription description, ServiceHostBase serviceHost)
   bei System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime()
   bei System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   bei Peripherie.WinService.Service.OnStart(String[] args) in c:\Users\Xyanid\Dropbox\Visual Studio Projects\Peripherie\Software\Se

Comment: @DokutoMekki: please **do not** put code samples, long error messags or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: I accept this answer because it got me on the track where to find my error, just in case anyone is confused. This is because all of the error were in the config file, so SouthShoreAKs answer is more or less the clue to it.